# Puppet Network module sets enable on every run

Tags: puppet

Using razorsedge-network (v3.6.0)

On every puppet run, I get the following:
`Notice: /Stage[main]/Network/Service[network]/enable: enable changed 'false' to 'true'`

Client is running CentOS 7.1, tried with agents 4.2.1 and 4.2.3.
Puppetmaster is PE 2015

It seems to rely on SysV scripts, but that has everything set correctly:

```
[root@srv08 ~]# service network status
Configured devices:
lo ens160
Currently active devices:
lo ens160
[root@srv08 ~]# echo $?
0
```

The manifest is called as:

```
class profiles::networking {

  $allinterfaces = split($::interfaces, ',')
  $pri_if = $allinterfaces[0]

  ::network::if::static {$pri_if:
    ensure    => hiera('network::if::static:ensure'),
    ipaddress => hiera('network::if::static:ipaddress'),
    netmask   => hiera('network::if::static:netmask'),
    gateway   => hiera('network::if::static:gateway'),
    peerdns   => true,
    dns1      => hiera('network::if::static:dns1'),
    dns2      => hiera('network::if::static:dns2'),
    domain    => hiera('network::if::static:domain'),
  }
}
```

Hiera in turn returns the single value

Comment: not sure this is enough information to troubleshoot.. what network module, what version of said network module, and what params for said network module do you have set via a manifest or hiera?

Comment: Sure, the module detail is in the first line, razorsedge-network (v3.6.0)
I am using hiera for the config

Comment: thanks for that.. params?

Comment: Post updated, thanks

Comment: well. something is notifying the service. the service definition is pretty straight forward https://github.com/razorsedge/puppet-network/blob/3.6.0/manifests/init.pp#L34-L38

Comment: Well, it is not trying to start or restart the service though, it is trying to enable it at boot:
"enable changed 'false' to 'true'"

Answer (score 0):

Because the network service doesn't remain up after you start it. So at each invocation the service is seen as "exited" and puppet is trying to start it again

Comment: Well, no... 
Puppet is not trying to start it (as it would do if a service is not started), it is repeatedly trying to set enable. Thus puppet is under the impression it is not set to start at boot.
Yet both systemctl and chkconfig reports it is set to start

Answer (score 0):

Not the proper way I am sure, but I 'solved' it by adding this to my manifest:

```
  file_line { 'Kill enabled':
    ensure => 'absent',
    line => '    enable     => true,',
    path => '/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/network/manifests/init.pp',
  }
```

So basically remove the enable line. I had to do it in the manifest as the module is controlled by Puppetfile, this will ensure it stays absent.